# How to not show angular ui datepicker dropdown together

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I have used [this Bootstrap datepicker with angular directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker). It works fine. Now I need to one more little customization. When clicking first input, it will show first dropdown calender. Clicking another opens another calender dropdown. All I need now those dropdown won't show together. I mean when first dropdown is open, clicking on second input will open second dropdown as well as **first dropdown should close**. Similarly, when second dropdown is open, clicking on first input will open first calender dropdown and **second dropdown should be close**.

> [image]

So, I need to do something like similar:

```
when date1 is open
close date2 if it is open
when date2 is open
close date1 if it is open
```

But, as I am new in angular, I don't understand how to do that in angular way. How to do that?

[Plunker work](http://plnkr.co/edit/vKZmbZZp9Zct7BtlLZIw?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only 2 datepicker then you can do it like this in place of

```
 $scope.open[date] = true;
```

put this

```
if(date=== 'date4'){
        $scope.open['date4'] = true;
        $scope.open['date5'] = false;
      }else{
        $scope.open['date4'] = false;
        $scope.open['date5'] = true;
      }
```

And if you have multiple datepicker then you can call loop to close them.